# docker run entrypoint with multiple commands

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can I have an entrypoint in a `docker run` which executes multiple commands?
Something like:

```
docker run --entrypoint "echo 'hello' && echo 'world'" ... <image>
```

The image I'm trying to run, has already an entrypoint set in the Dockerfile, so solution like the following seems not to work, because it looks my commands are ignored, and only the original entrypoint is executed

```
docker run ... <image> bash -c "echo 'hello' && echo 'world'"
```

In my use-case I must use the `docker run` command. Solution which change the `Dockerfile` are not acceptable, since it is not in my hands

Comment: Can you create a bash script with all the commands and use that as an input to entrypoint? Not sure if that would work though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As a style point, this gets vastly easier if your image has a `CMD` that can be overridden.  If you only need to run one command with no initial setup, make it be the `CMD` and not the `ENTRYPOINT`:

```sh
CMD ./some_command  # not ENTRYPOINT
```

If you need to do some initial setup and then launch the main command, make the `ENTRYPOINT` be a shell script that ends with the special instruction `exec "$@"`.  The `CMD` will be passed into it as parameters, and this line replaces the shell script with that command.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh
... do first time setup, run database migrations, set variables ...
exec "$@"
```

```sh
# Dockerfile
...
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # MUST be JSON-array syntax
CMD ./some_command             # as before
```

If you do these things, then you can use your initial `docker run` form.  This will replace the `CMD` but leave the `ENTRYPOINT` intact.  In the wrapper-script case, your alternate command will be run as the `exec "$@"` command, so all of the first-time setup will be done first.

```sh
# Assuming the image correctly honors the CMD
docker run ... \
  image-name \
  sh -c 'echo "foo is $FOO" && echo "bar is $BAR"'
```

If you really can't do this, you can override the `docker run --entrypoint`.  This runs *instead of* the image's entrypoint (if you want the image's entrypoint you have to run it yourself), and the syntax is awkward:

```sh
# Run a shell command instead of the entrypoint
docker run ... \
  --entrypoint /bin/sh \
  image-name \
  -c 'echo "foo is $FOO" && echo "bar is $BAR"'
```

Note that the `--entrypoint` option comes *before* the image name, and its arguments come *after* the image name.

Comment: a slightly modified version of @David Maze's answer is what worked for me: `docker run -it --entrypoint sh my_docker './commands.sh'` where commands.sh are a set of commands that live inside the docker (without the `exec "$@"` part)

Comment: This is the best answer I've found for my use case after 2 days of Googling. I have a tiny Alpine container-based service that requires another tiny companion cron job. I want the `cornd` command to be always running and the service boot command overwritable by docker. So I put `crond` inside ENTRYPOINT and service boot inside CMD. `exec "$@"` did the trick to connect them together. Previously I tried `&&` but did not work.