# How can I run two PHP scripts using Docker?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rabbitmq

I have an application, that work with rabbitmq. There is 2 php scripts (send and receive messages) but i can run only one script using Dockerfile

```
CMD ["php", "./send.php"]
```

But i have to run two scripts. My tutor ask me to do two containers for each script:

```
version: "3"

services:

  rabbit_mq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ./docker/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ./docker/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
      - ./docker/rabbitmq/conf/:/var/conf/rabbitmq
    environment:
      - API_URL=Api:8000

  send:
    build:
      context: './docker'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:7.4.cli
    container_name: send
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - rabbit_mq

  receive:
    image: php:7.4.cli
#    build:
#      context: './docker'
#      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: receive
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - rabbit_mq
```

What can I do to run 2 scripts using "docker-compose up" command? I serf a lot of web-pages, but couldn't find anything, I really need your help!

Comment: You run 2 docker containers, each with it's own PHP script. Not one container with 2 scripts.

Comment: Is the PHP script always running? Or does it run once when the container is built? If they're not being continuously ran, you could probably set-up a cronjob inside the docker container that runs the two scripts every x-minutes

Comment: Why not use a bash script that triggers both scripts?

Comment: @Moudi scripts have to run always, but I will think about what you wrote

Comment: @NicoHaase my tutor ask me not to do this :( 
but i tried this at the first time

Comment: Your tutor probably wants you to discover entry point scripts? [docker run entrypoint with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652198/docker-run-entrypoint-with-multiple-commands)

Comment: I think you need something like supervisor, you can define multiple scripts that will be restarted if crashed

Comment: Why not ask your tutor for alternatives then?

Comment: @NicoHaase i really want to do it by myself at the beginning :)
and also i dont want to distract him

Comment: You're pretty much there with the docker-compose file you show. Have your existing Dockerfile run the send script. Then make a second Dockerfile for the receive script and have the `receive` container run that.

Comment: @HansKilian okey! i'll try this one

Answer (score 1):

you did not specify if those scripts terminate process or not, but to run them, you can make docker-compose like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  rabbit_mq:
    # existing configuration

  send:
    # existing configuration
    command: ["php", "./send.php"]

  receive:
    # existing configuration
    command: ["php", "./receive.php"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to run it as part of the docker-compose you can add these lines to certain container blocks in the composer file:

```
command: php send.php
command: php receive.php
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command

If you need more complicated things like restarting on failure, take a look at using `supervisor'.